# REST API Set of possible values: strings or integers?

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing a REST API and have run across this issue:

How should a set of values be defined?

Say I have a Picture object that is going to be requested at http://myserver.com/api/getPicture/1

so the server responds:

```
{
 url : "http://myserver.com/pictures/1.jpg",
 taken_at : "1/1/2012"
}
```

Now, say I wanted to add a color_depth field.

Two possible choices to do this are:

```
color_depth : "BLACK_WHITE" or "COLOR" or "GRAYSCALE"
color_depth : "0" OR "1" OR "2" //would need to map these to their meaning somewhere
```

Is there a standard for what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For JSON, there isn't any de-facto or official standard. [JSON-SCHEMA](http://www.json-schema.org/) tries to solve this, but the specs aren't recommended yet and even implementations aren't popular.

Using XML, [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema#dev) is the standard solution. For RDF, there is also RDFS that solves this problem.

For every format, the coice is yours. Depending on integer identifiers (1, 2, 3) and translating them without a schema means that your requests are far less self-contained than strings that express what they mean like "COLOR". It is a core concept of RESTful API design that requests should be self-contained. This loosely relates to the [visibility property](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/net_app_arch.htm#sec_2_3_5) of RESTful architectures described in the Roy Fielding dissertation.

I would go for full strings.

Comment: Agreed. Integer codes are a great way to 1) save typing time, 2) save bytes on the wire or on disk, and 3) save a user the pain of remembering whether the value was "BLACK_WHITE" or "BLACK-WHITE" or "B&W" or what-have-you. If the server gives the client the available choices in a form control, or by some other means, then the use case for integer codes fades rapidly.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using full strings. Any benefits of memory/speed are only applicable in really large amounts of data, plus now I can just look at responses and know what they are saying without having to remember integer codes.

Comment: P.S. There are similar debates for storing "enums" like these in databases, which is something I missed when I posted this question.